# What is a more efficient way to only count alphanumeric characters in an array of String?

Tags: c#, .net, counting, alphanumeric

I want to only count alphanumerics in a string array - no spaces, punctuation, etc.

I have this clunky code:

```
private int GetCountOfCharsInDoc(string[] _lines)
{
    int iCountOfChars = 0;
    string sLine;
    foreach (string line in _lines)
    {
        sLine = line.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace(".", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace("?", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace(",", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace(";", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace(":", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace("(", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace(")", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace("'", string.Empty);
        sLine = line.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        iCountOfChars = iCountOfChars + sLine.Count();
    }
    return iCountOfChars;
}
```

What is a better/more efficient way of only counting alphanumerics?

Comment: Just FYI, your code above won't even work the way you expect it to as only the last line that replaces the quote is actually doing anything.  All of the other characters you  "removed" are still there because each call is using the original `line` variable and not the returned variable `sLine`.  To fix this, change all occurrences of `line` INSIDE the loop to `sLine` except for the very FIRST one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`char.IsLetterOrDigit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletterordigit?view=netcore-3.1) method to get only alphanumerics, [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) from `System.Linq` to count them and finally [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Nullable_System_Int32___) to get a total count.

```cs
private int GetCountOfCharsInDoc(string[] _lines)
{
    return _lines.Sum(line => line.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Char.IsLetter` and `Char.IsDigit`:

```
_lines.Sum(s => s.Count(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || Char.IsDigit(c)))
```

or just:

```
_lines.Sum(s => s.Count(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to use Linq, you could iterate through each character and check it with `char.IsLetterOrDigit()`:

```
int n = 0;
foreach (string line in _lines) {
    foreach (char c in line) {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) n++;
    }
}
return n;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use **regular expression** for extract only alphanumeric from your text, then count it.

the code be like :

```
 var text = "your string";
 var count = Regex.Replace(text , @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").Count();
```